# You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1). M1 Mac

Tags: reactjs, npm

----- Update - Solved ----

using `yarn create react-app my-app` seems to work for me.

---

Attempting to create a new react app and facing this problem.. Other peoples solutions haven't worked for me so posting the steps I took so far.

`npx create-react-app my-app`

returns

```
You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

Both suggested commands do not seem to fix the issue.

`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

```
up to date, audited 1 package in 131ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

`yarn global remove create-react-app`

```
yarn global v1.22.17
warning package.json: No license field
[1/2]   Removing module create-react-app...
error This module isn't specified in a package.json file.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
```

Attempted to clear cache as some suggested

`npx clear-npx-cache`

```
Need to install the following packages:
  clear-npx-cache
Ok to proceed? (y) y
```

Not much happened there

attempted to locate the react install
`npm ls -g create-react-app`

```
/usr/local/lib
└── (empty)
```

tried the @latest as some suggested as well

`npx create-react-app@latest my-app`

```
Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app@latest
Ok to proceed? (y) y
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

I'm using a 13" M1 running macOS 12.3.1

----- Update -----

I reinstalled it globally then uninstalled it as some suggested now this happens.

`npm install -g create-react-app`
`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
`npx create-react-app my-app`

```
A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.
```

[package.json image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTcdJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Then open `C:\Users\Your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`
delete everything in the folders.

Open `C:\Users\Your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm` delete everything related to `create-react-app`

Then finally :

```
npx create-react-app my-project
```